# Why is my JavaScript function not working on all of my buttons?

Tags: javascript, function

Can I call a JavaScript function on two different elements with different ids?

**HTML**

```
<p id="id1">12</p>
<button type="button" onClick="ABC(document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML)">one</button>

<input type="text" id="id2" value="21"/>
<button type="button" onClick="ABC(document.getElementById('id2').innerHTML)">two</button>
```

**JS**

```
function ABC(id = null) {
    if(id) {    
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {id: id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(result) {
            }
        });  
    } 
}
```

The function is not working on the second button and I don't know why.

Comment: `following script not worked for me.` is not a really helpfull description. Do you get any error message? What happens when `ABC` is called and howis it idffernt to what it should do?

Comment: That code should work if `ABC` is a global function, other than the fact that `input` elements don't have any `innerHTML`; they have `value`. So the second call will always pass `""` into `ABC`.

Comment: There are no div elements in your example.

Comment: @JennyO'Reilly these buttons are located in two different div tags, And i don't want to share a bunch of code.

Comment: Well then it is like T.J. said: At your second button you pass the innerHTML of an input element as the id. That is always an empty string which in JS is a falsy value. Therefore the AJAX request is never executed when you click the second button.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you now its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the second button use input data so you should use document.getElementById('id2').value

```js
function ABC(id = null) {
    if(id) {    
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {id: id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(result) {
            }
        });  
    } 
}
```

```html
<p id="id1">12</p>
<button type="button" onClick="ABC(document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML)">one</button>

<input type="text" id="id2" value="21"/>
<button type="button" onClick="ABC(document.getElementById('id2').value)">two</button>
```